# Filtrar valores menores a 5 en MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos

Buen dia, Comunidad me pueden apoyar con una sentencia de búsqueda en MySQL?

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT P.id_producto,P.descripcion,p.unidad,p.linea,p.Ubicacion,
IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) entradas, IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0)
salida, IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) -IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) stock
FROM catalogo P LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad) 
total_entradas FROM entradas GROUP BY id_producto) E ON P.id_producto
= E.id_producto LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_producto, 
SUM(cantidad)total_salidas FROM salida GROUP BY id_producto) S ON 
P.id_producto = S.id_producto
```

y me da este resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero filtrar en la columna stock los valores menores que 5. Alguien que me de alguna idea cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas agregar la clausula `where` al final de tu consulta, en este caso `stock`, es el nombre que utilizas, tendrías que condicionar solo a donde este sea menor a 5.

```
SELECT 
    P.id_producto,
    P.descripcion,
    p.unidad,
    p.linea,
    p.Ubicacion,
    IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) entradas,
    IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) salida,
    IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) - IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) stock
FROM
    catalogo P
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id_producto, SUM(cantidad) total_entradas
    FROM
        entradas
    GROUP BY id_producto) E ON P.id_producto = E.id_producto
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id_producto, SUM(cantidad) total_salidas
    FROM
        salida
    GROUP BY id_producto) S ON P.id_producto = S.id_producto
WHERE stock < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade al final de tu consulta: `WHERE stock<5`

Comment: Siempre una explicación de lo que se expone como respuesta se agradece, checa [answer]